# how to get the value of breadcrumb link click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '.woocommerce-breadcrumb', function() {
  var eventLabel = jQuery(this).children('a').text().trim();
  console.log(eventLabel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class ="woocommerce-breadcrumb"> 
  <a href="#">home</a>
  <i class ="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
  <a href ="#">music</a>
  <i class ="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
  "album"
</nav>
```

HomeMusic
home>music>album  ==> when i click music or home both home and music printing but i want to print only the clicked link

Comment: this is my code => jQuery(document).on('click', '.woocommerce-breadcrumb', function() {
var eventLabel = jQuery(this).children('a').text().trim();
console.log(eventLabel)
});

Comment: so why are you not binding to the anchor? `.....on('click', '.woocommerce-breadcrumb a', function () { console.log($(this).text()); })`

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.woocommerce-breadcrumb a', function() {
  var eventLabel = jQuery(this).text().trim();
  console.log(eventLabel)
});
```

I've moved the reference to `a` into `'.woocommerce-breadcrumb'` and removed the `.find()`

**Demo**

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '.woocommerce-breadcrumb a', function() {
  var eventLabel = jQuery(this).text().trim();
  console.log(eventLabel)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="woocommerce-breadcrumb">
  <a href="#">home</a>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
  <a href="#">music</a>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> "album" </nav>
```